# What alternative to "getTextDirection()" in Android API older than 17?

Tags: android

In an Android app, we wish to have an iOS-like horizontal scroll wheel, and we are using [HorizontalPicker](https://github.com/blazsolar/HorizontalPicker).

This requires API 17 for calls **getTextDirection()** and **getLayoutDirection()**.

For getTextDirection, the usage is:

```
        switch (getTextDirection()) {
            default:
            case TEXT_DIRECTION_FIRST_STRONG:
                return (defaultIsRtl ? TextDirectionHeuristicsCompat.FIRSTSTRONG_RTL :
                        TextDirectionHeuristicsCompat.FIRSTSTRONG_LTR);
            case TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL:
                return TextDirectionHeuristicsCompat.ANYRTL_LTR;
            case TEXT_DIRECTION_LTR:
                return TextDirectionHeuristicsCompat.LTR;
            case TEXT_DIRECTION_RTL:
                return TextDirectionHeuristicsCompat.RTL;
            case TEXT_DIRECTION_LOCALE:
                return TextDirectionHeuristicsCompat.LOCALE;
        }
```

Looking at dashboard, I see ~20% of devices using APIs 15 or 16, so I'm thinking we should target API 15 rather than 17.

How should I change this code?

1. Is there a way to only run this code if the device is new enough?  If so, what should the function return for an older device?
2. Is there an alternative mechanism I should rewrite this method to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind.  Leaving this question here in case it is useful to others, to know how to work around APIs missing in a given version.

My real issue was not knowing how to mark the calls so that "lint" would not complain about them.

Here is the complete implementation in HorizontalPicker:

```
private TextDirectionHeuristicCompat getTextDirectionHeuristic() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {

        return TextDirectionHeuristicsCompat.FIRSTSTRONG_LTR;

    } else {

        // Always need to resolve layout direction first
        final boolean defaultIsRtl = (getLayoutDirection() == LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);

        switch (getTextDirection()) {
            default:
            case TEXT_DIRECTION_FIRST_STRONG:
                return (defaultIsRtl ? TextDirectionHeuristicsCompat.FIRSTSTRONG_RTL :
                        TextDirectionHeuristicsCompat.FIRSTSTRONG_LTR);
            case TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL:
                return TextDirectionHeuristicsCompat.ANYRTL_LTR;
            case TEXT_DIRECTION_LTR:
                return TextDirectionHeuristicsCompat.LTR;
            case TEXT_DIRECTION_RTL:
                return TextDirectionHeuristicsCompat.RTL;
            case TEXT_DIRECTION_LOCALE:
                return TextDirectionHeuristicsCompat.LOCALE;
        }
    }
}
```

It already has logic to handle older builds!

So all that is needed is to mark the two calls **getLayoutDirection()** and **getTextDirection()** so that lint does not complain.

The simplest way to do so, without hiding problems elsewhere, is to mark this method to suppress lint complaints about API versions:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private TextDirectionHeuristicCompat getTextDirectionHeuristic() {
...
```

CAUTION: Only make such a change, after examining the lint complaints and the logic, and your **AndroidManifest.xml**, to be sure the complaints can be safely ignored.

In my case, manifest has minimum API = 15 and target API = 19, the two complaints were "Call requires API level 17, minimum is 15)", and

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
```

directs all devices less than 17 to use the one-line implementation, which does not use the API 17 calls. That is, the calls will only be made on devices with API 17 or above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewCompat from android.support.v4 with something like :

```
if (ViewCompat.getLayoutDirection(mView) == ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) {
    //...
}
```